# How do I obtained a signed and secure HTTPs/SSL certificate for my company's site?

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, warnings, signed

I've tried to search stackoverflow for an answer to this, and I've been around on google - to no avail.

Can you please help me understand what I need to do to get a signed and secure SSL/HTTPs for my company's site?

I'm trying to avoid the current warning at https://attensi.com/

Thank you so much for any help.

/ Frustrated game developer trying to play webdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be using self signed or Free SSL Certificate for your website. In such case browser display "**The site's security certificate is not trusted!**" warning message. To remove this error message you need to install SSL certificate issued by trusted Certificate Authorities like Symantec, GeoTrust, Thawte, etc.

Comment: Thanks, got the same response on Twitter so I'll buy one of those.